# How to get table cell value with javascript by attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flexigrid

```
function getSelectedCopyDates() {
            var arr = new Array();
                //for every row that has a checked checkbox
                $("tr").has(".noteCheckBox:checked").each(function (i) {
                    if ($(this).id !== "checkAllNotes"){//since this doesn't have a "abbr=..." it breaks the code below "# syntax error"
                        //push the value of column(FName, LName) into the array 
                        arr.push($("#" + this.id + "> td[abbr='EventDate'] > div").text());
                    }
                });
            return arr;
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by "cell value" you're just looking to get the text inside the `<td>` then you could do something like **[`this`](http://jsfiddle.net/cZMXe/)**:

**HTML**:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" abbr="FName, LName">RAWR</td>
    </tr>        
</table>​
```

**jQuery**:

```
$("td[abbr='FName, LName']").text();
```

You can use jQuery's [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method to get the value within the given element.

**EDIT**:

Saw you needed to get only the `<td>`s where they contain checkboxes that are checked, so this may work for you:

```
$("td[abbr='FName, LName'] > input:checked").parent().text();
```

Find all the `td[abbr='FName, LName'` that contain an input that is checked, then get the text of the that elements parent.

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cZMXe/1/)**

```
//You won't need the on change event for you code. I only added it here to show you what happens when there are values and when there are no values.

$("input").on("change", function(){
    var arr = new Array();

    //for every row that has a checked checkbox
    $("tr").has(".noteCheckBox:checked").each(function(i){
       //push the value of column 5 (FName, LName) into the array 
       arr.push($("#"+this.id + "> td > div.c5").text());       
    });
    //Print the array to the console.
    console.log(arr);
});​
```

**[UPDATED EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Qjxd9/2/)**

**EDIT**:

your function should be:

```
function getSelectedInvestigatorNames() {
   var arr = new Array();

   //for every row that has a checked checkbox
   $("tr").has(".noteCheckBox:checked").each(function(i){
      //push the value of column 5 (FName, LName) into the array 
      arr.push($("#"+this.id + "> td[abbr='FName, LName'] > div").text());       
   });

   return arr;
}
```

Comment: The OP wants the table cell by attribute rather than all cells, [abbr=XXXX] would get what's needed, though.

Comment: Anyway you can show me the code you're using? Update your original post and I'll take a look.

Comment: Alright, check out this new fiddle example and see if it helps any: http://jsfiddle.net/Qjxd9/2/

Comment: The latest update in my answer is my code wrapped in your function. This should return an array of all the names. Hope it helps.

Comment: You sir, are a gorgeous person. HAHA I cannot describe how happy I am!!. Thank you so much for your persistance

Comment: I'm glad I could help, even if it did take us a while to get on the same page =) Good luck with the project and you're very welcome.

Comment: I think this will be the last time i bug you. But I noticed that when I click on the "checkAllNotes" which checks all the boxes, it craps out since it doesnt contain an "abbr" attribute. I've tried to filter it with an if statement to check if it is that id but it seems wrong. Cant you take a look at that pleasE? I will post it. Sorry about this

Comment: Yeah, I'll have some down time here shortly (leaving work/driving home), but I'll take a look as soon as I can.

Comment: If you wouldn't mind, please post the relevant `checkAllNotes` code so I can see what that is.

Comment: Sorry about that. I had no access to the code during the weekend. I have posted the code in my main question to show the checkbox

Answer (score 3):

Try this

This is to get the text inside td

```
 $('td[abbr="FName, LName"]').text();
```

OR

```
$('td[abbr*="FName"][abbr*="LName"]').text();
```

To get the value Try this

```
$('td[abbr*="FName"][abbr*="LName"]').attr('value')
```

[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/xp5sE/1/)

[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/xp5sE/2/)

Comment: only problem with this I am having is it is grabbing all the values, so since I have 15 rows, it grabs it 15 times. How can I get it to only grab the rows where a checkbox is checked

Comment: @user1084319, I've added an update as well to check for checkboxes that are checked if it helps. Good luck!